# How to turn a java Json data Fetching class into a method?

Tags: java, android, json, methods

I got a method that fetch data from a web service, so Im looking for a way to call it as a method.
How can I turn this code into a method? or can I call a class in a method? because it has a protected method and extended from a class, but if I implemented the extended class `AsyncTask` to the class I need to use the Json fetching protected method `doInBackground` it says "Interface expexted here".
Here's my code that I need to convert it to a method or a way to add it to the class I want to use it in:

> Notice: I already extended `AppCompatActivity` to the class I want to call doInBackground in so I cannot extend `FetchData` class.

Thanks a lot :D

````
package com.example.wordspuzzlejsontest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;





public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String update = "4";
    String data = "";
    int currentLevel;

    Context context;

    FetchData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e42776dd18e4016617690ce/" + update);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            currentLevel = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentLevel", 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length();) {

                i = currentLevel;
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);


                String id = (String) JO.get("id");
                String img = (String) JO.get("img");
                String w1 = (String) JO.get("w1");
                String w2 = (String) JO.get("w2");
                String w3 = (String) JO.get("w3");
                String w4 = (String) JO.get("w4");

                editor.putString("id" + i, id);
                editor.putString("img" + i, img);
                editor.putString("w1" + i, w1);
                editor.putString("w2" + i, w2);
                editor.putString("w3" + i, w3);
                editor.putString("w4" + i, w4);

                editor.apply();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}


```
````

Comment: You can create pojo class for this json data.

Comment: Since it is protected, you can extend `FetchData.class` and have a public method which calls this protected method like `this.doInBackground()`

Comment: @papaya do you mean to import FetchData.class? because I cannot extends multiple classes.

Comment: Why can't you write `class NewClass extends FetchData` and have a method like `public Void fetchData(){ this.doInBackground();}`

Comment: @papaya I did it, and called the doInBackground method like this: `NewClass.fetchData(); the error is pointing to fetchData(); and says "Non-statifc method 'fetchData();' cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: You have to create a new object from `NewClass  newClass = new NewClass();` and then do `newClass.fetchData();`. Are you not familiar with java at all ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up my comments:

Create a new class called `NewClass.java`

```
class NewClass extends FetchData{
  public Void fetchData(Void... voids){ return this.doInBackground(voids);}
}
```

Since `doInBackground` in a protected method, you will have private access inside `NewClass.java`